# Загрузка аватарки в группу ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты.
Столкнулся с такой задачей:
Нужно загрузить аватар в группу вк.
В процессе загрузки аватара в группу ВК отправляю post-запрос, а в ответ получаю следующее:

```
{"error":"ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SIGNATURE","bwact":"owner_photo","server":618927,"_sig":"104f02c0232b4a64ad6d8dfb0a45b477"}
```

post-запрос выглядит так:

```
$sent_image = dirname(__FILE__)."/iovov.jpg";

$post = array(
'photo'=>'@'.$sent_image,
);
```

Адрес post-запроса такого плана:

```
http://cs618927.vk.com/upload.php?act=owner_photo&oid=-7774160&square=&mid=15268686&server=618927&_origin=http%3A%2F%2Fvk.com&_sig=104f02c0232b4a64ad6d8dfb0a45b477&
```

**Помогите. Как решить данную проблему и загрузить, получить нужный ответ с запроса, а не ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SIGNATURE**.

Comment: @Workaholic, как посылается запрос? Не посылаете ли вы просто адрес картинки на сервер?

Comment: Etki, запрос отправляется на ссылку в самом низу сообщения ("Адрес post запроса такого плана" - это ссылка, выглядит как пост запрос). 

И отправляю пост запрос с изображением (параметр $post) , который чуть выше ссылки...

Хочется загрузить аватар без использования api

Comment: @Workaholic, я и говорю - вот таким вот образом отправляется не сам файл, а путь на локальной машине к нему.

Comment: Etki, и как быть? на другом сайте загружал подобным образом, и все получалось...

Comment: @Workaholic, выложить полный код запроса, как я и просил, для начала.

Comment: Etki, вот все, до куда пока дошел..
http://pastebin.com/rewfMaWC

Comment: @Workaholic, 

1. Здесь все равно не видно, как формируется запрос.
2. Вы слышали про такие вещи, как api? http://vk.com/dev/photos.saveOwnerPhoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если наберётесь храбрости всё сделать по-белому, в документации подробно описан [процесс загрузки фотографии](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) в сообщество.

[Запросы к API](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests) лучше выполнять с помощью [curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-exec.php).

Вам понадобится [создать своё приложение](https://vk.com/editapp?act=create) ВК (типа «Сайт»), [авторизовать](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) его, получив token, который будет использован при выполнении запросов к api.

Comment: sergiks,

1. скажите, а если я захочу получать информацию к примеру: с разных страниц людей вк, групп, что то добавлять, писать ссобщения им, не будет ли выскакивать у окно добавления приложения у них? - что то я этот момент не понял...

2. если к примеру я уже авторизовался в вк по логин-пароль, не через api, то у меня не получится воспользоваться их методами(загрузить картинку в группу)?

скрипты свои запускаю с денвера

могли бы привести пример кода, как это должно выглядеть, чтобы после его можно было работать уже с методами api

Comment: @Workaholic, описанный выше способ подразумевает наличие сервера в сети и домена, по которому к нему обращаться.

Если задачи у вас не масштабные, только-для-себя, можете создать приложение "Standalone"-типа, якобы оно на мобильном работает. У такого гораздо больше полномочий, но периодически может требоваться распознать капчу - т.е. не годится для автономной долгой работы.

 1. Т.е. у вас их логин-пароль есть? Нет, у них ничего не выскочит.

 2. Авторизация по логину-паролю для API, кажется, давно отменена. Теперь только OAuth2.0